# Codeigniter Javascript dynamic inputs only submitting first item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to submit a form with dynamic inputs. I am able to add a several inputs via the javascript. However, when I submit, it only picks up the first added input value. I hope someone can take a look at this for me as I've tried to fix this for so long. Thank you

Controller

```
public function update(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Firstname', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Lastname', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_number', 'Phone', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_of_birth', 'Date of Birth', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('active', 'Is Active', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $person_id = $this->input->post('person_id');
        $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
        $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
        $date_of_birth = $this->input->post('date_of_birth');
        $phone_number = $this->input->post('phone_number');
        $account_number = $this->input->post('account_number');
        $address = $this->input->post('address');
        $country = $this->input->post('country');
        $active = $this->input->post('active');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
            $this->edit();
        }else{
            $person = array(
                'first_name'=>$first_name,
                'last_name'=>$last_name,
                'date_of_birth'=>$date_of_birth,
                'phone_number'=>$phone_number,
                'address'=>$address,
                'country'=>$country,
            );
            $account = array(
                'is_active'=>$active
            );
            print_r($account_number);
        }
    }
```

View

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 5;
    var wrapper = $("#new_account_number_container");
    var addInput = $("#addInput");
    var i;
    $(addInput).click(function(e){
        i = $("#new_account_number_container input").length;
        e.preventDefault();
        if(i<max_fields){
            i++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="account_number[]"  class="form-control" placeholder="Account Number" required autofocus><a href="#" style="color:#2c3137 !important; " class="remove">Remove</a><div>');
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
        i--;
    });
});
</script>
<div id="new_account_number_container" class="form-group col-sm-8">
           <input type="text" name="account_number[]"  class="form-control" placeholder="Account Number" autofocus>
           <br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
            <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary" id="addInput">Add</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should submit the form using jquery/javascript.

Comment: But how would I do that? I thought if I added a [] to the name it should work as its registered as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I can not see `<form>` in your code. Without this tag, you can not get desired behaviour:

After that,

To give you formatted code snippet I am posting that suggestion as an answer:

// this is the id of the form
$("#form_id").submit(function(e) {

```
var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#form_id").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

     e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to remember that, PHP serves as back-end application. So anything dynamic (like DOM input text in your case) may NOT be submitted simply because the `<form>` tag is not updated that you have new text-box input.

One of the thing you could do is to use ajax for form submitting. Because it is Client-Side Script, it could detect all DOM input text box on your page, and serialized it before send the request to the back-end.

First by adding a `<form>` tag  between  your input and button component. Example like `<form id="frm" name="frm">`.

Second, by adding a button which trigger a JavaScript function.

```
function update(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")==true){
        $.post(
            "*absolute_project_root_path*/*controller*/update",
            $('#frm').serialize(),
            function(response){                 
                //what to do with your response..
            }
        );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can access the submitted form in the back-end like usual.